# Strange behaviour of plot.xts when adding vertical lines to a plot

Tags: r, plot, xts

I am experiencing a really strange issue when trying to add vertical lines to an existing plot of an xts object. The following code should allow you to reproduce my problem.

```
require(xts)
data("sample_matrix")
test <- xts(coredata(sample_matrix)[,1], order.by = as.Date(index(sample_matrix)))
plot.xts(test)
addEventLines(events = xts(x = '', order.by = as.Date('1970-04-01')), lty = 2, col = 'red', lwd = 1.5)
```

What happens is that when I run the first four lines code up to the last line, everything works fine and the plot looks exactly as I want it to be. Still, after running the last line of code, magics happens and the background vertical lines, for no apparent reason, get cut at both ends. Here are the two plots before and after running the last line of code:

[image]

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Depending on the size of the window in RStudio I sometimes get the problem and sometimes not. Maybe it is related to the figure margins? Have you tried directly writing the plot as an image?

Comment: @CalvinWhealton Nothing, I tried to write it as an image but the problem still persist. This thing is driving me crazy...